# How can I find the pbmpak.c file over the internet?

Tags: c, image-processing

I have a source code that included `"pbmpak.h"` and I need the implementation of this header(pbmpak.c) to run the program. I found the header and downloaded that but I can't find the implementation.

Comment: I think you need `pbm` library source code, whatever that is.

Comment: The source code is not mine. I'm trying to test that. The source code has
`#include "pbmpak.h"` and 
`#include  "pbmpak.c"`. It seems that the prior developer used like this. how can I use `pmb` library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take a look on github. I found this quite easily

https://github.com/FlybyMedia/3rd-party-localize/blob/master/PBMLIB/pbmpak.c

There are quite a few references that might get you started here...

https://github.com/search?q=pbmpak&ref=searchresults&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should be able to get everything from [netpbm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/).  That is the suite that contains all the relevant conversion routines and looking at pbmpak.h, probably contains all the function definitions.  Notice that `netpbm` replaced `pbmplus` suite.